# Pass bundle from adapter to tab fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity, bundle, android-recyclerview

[image: app flow]

I have fragment1 with recycler view that displays list if cardviews
When I click on a card it goes to tabfragment which contains different tabs of which one is a detail tab with detail info of the selected card view.

In the adapter of the recycler where I listen for the onClick of the card view I grab all the detail info of the selected cardview and put it in a bundle.

I think I have to pass this to the main activity and retrieve it from the main activity with the detail fragment with an interface, but I can't seem to figure this out.

Where do I create the interface in the adapter? can someone give me some sample code and how do I send the bundle to Main Activity and retrieve it in the detail fragment? If you need me to post some part of the code let me know not sure what to post.

Thanks!

Comment: here  it is explained nicely :- https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured it out from notes all over.
Essentially I created a separate Interface.

```
package com.tiretire.apps.salesapp.Util;
import android.os.Bundle;
public interface OnClickProductItem {
   public void onClickProductItem(Bundle bundle);
}
```

Send the bundle from the Adapter Class of the Recycler View via the interface to the Main Activity

```
private OnClickProductItem sendBundle;
sendBundle.onClickProductItem(bundle);
```

Then in the MainActivity Receive and have ready to send to DetailFragment:

```
@Override
public void onClickProductItem(Bundle bundle){
    ProductBundle = bundle;
}

public Bundle SendProductBundle(){
    return ProductBundle;
}
```

Last step retrieve from MainActivity into DetailFragment:

```
MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity)getActivity();
productBundle = mainActivity.SendProductBundle();
```

Hope this helps someone.